# Full sized (104-key US/ANSI) programmable keyboard (Via)

Tags: keyboards

I think I'm looking for a bit of a unicorn. I've done a lot of searching, and found plenty of programmable keyboards, plenty of full sized keyboards, but the only one I've found that is full sized, programmable, and [US style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#Windows_keyboards) is the Keychron Q6.

Are there any others? I'm not opposed to the Keychron; I would just like other options if they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MONSGEEK M5](https://meow-key.com/products/monsgeek-m5-diy-kit-100?sca_ref=4995306.YXx3PPSYB1) is also full sized and fully programmable using QMK/VIA.

[image]

Keychron also makes the V6, C2 Pro, K5 Pro, K10 Pro, and Q6/Q6 Pro/Q6 Max, all of which support QMK/VIA.